# Does the phrase "to be selective with" mean what I want?

Tags: phrase-usage

> They didn't give us all the information about the matter. They were
>   **selective with** the truth.

I want to say that they intentionally gave only some of the truth about the matter and not some others.

Comment: some of the truth, part  of the  truth, not all the truth. "others" does not work here.

Comment: ***The where*** *selective* doesn't make any sense. Had you meant to type ***they were*** *selective*?

Comment: @JasonBassford Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=selective%20with%20the%20truth%2Ceconomical%20with%20the%20truth&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cselective%20with%20the%20truth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceconomical%20with%20the%20truth%3B%2Cc0) shows...

[image]

...the "idiomatic standard" here (particularly among politicians and pundits) is ***economical***. Arguably, there's a slight difference in emphasis between being *economical* (not giving out the *whole* truth) and *selective* (*choosing* which things to divulge). But in practice nobody would be likely to care about such fine distinctions.

I certainly don't mean to imply there's anything "wrong" with ***selective*** as used in the example. It's fine as it is. But it might be worth knowing that near-synonymous ***economical*** is *so* much more common for this exact context.

---

Note that being *economical / selective with the truth* is a kind of euphemistic understatement that normally implies ***lying*** (or at least, ***deliberately misleading***). An even more euphemistic variant was promoted by British politician Alan Clarke when referring to having made misleading statements about Britain's involvement in the Iraq war, when he admitted he'd been...

> ***economical . . . with the actualité***

...where using the French word ***actualité*** (intended to be understood as ***actuality*** = reality = truth, even though that's a poor translation) takes us even further away from clear direct English. Although everyone would understand his words, the choice of phrasing is itself an example of "attempting to mislead" (Clarke couldn't bring himself to admit that he actually ***lied and misled*** people).

Comment: I cannot understand how this answers the question.

Comment: @Lambie: And someone upvoted you for that! I'd have thought ***economical** (not giving out the whole truth) and **selective** (choosing which things to divulge)* was a fair summary of the (mostly theoretical in OP's context) tiny difference in "literal" meaning. Effectively, I've confirmed that OP's phrasing means what he wants it to mean, ***and*** pointed out (with supporting evidence) that although ***selective*** is perfectly valid here, ***economical*** is about 100 times more common. What do you (and your supporter) think I've failed to cover adequately?

Comment: Personally, I would only ever say "to be economical with the truth", as in parsimonious, in some **highly literary** context. You don't even bother to show how it would be used in a sentence. Also, l'actualité usually means the news (as in newspapers). full truth, all the truth, partial truth, not the whole truth. In fact, I see  no reason for the French at all. actualité does not mean truth at all in French.

Comment: @Lambie: That's a fair point about French ***actualité***. I (and Alan Clarke, I'm sure) know perfectly well that it doesn't exactly mean the same thing as English ***actuality***. But in practice that's how he *expected* his usage to be understood (mainly, I suppose, by people who don't have *intimate* knowledge of French), and there's no doubt it's been repeated countless times since his initial "coinage". The key point is ***all*** these usages are euphemistic, so virtually by definition, "literal" interpretations are somewhat missing the point.

Comment: actualité is a false friend. It does not mean: actuality at all. It means: currency, in fact. le problème actuel=the current problem. :) As for truth, it is very common to say half-truth, full truth, partial truth etc. Right?

Comment: @Lambie: It may be worth noting that NGram's "prevalence" for ***economical** with the truth* in the AmE corpus is 0.0000012% - about 7 times less than in the BrE corpus (where ***selective** with the truth* is too uncommon to figure on the chart). But even if OP's only interested in the *American* perspective, I'd have thought it was still worth knowing that even in AmE the ratio is over 30:1 in favour of ***economical***. But apparently no-one else here thinks this is relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, "to be selective with the truth" means to tell some truths but not others about a topic. It at least implies that the result is to mislead, by omitting significant aspects of the whole truth.

Comment: "The where selective with the truth"|| What  about that ?

Comment: @Lambie I take that as a typo for "they were"